# swift Firebase delete all snapshot child with given value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For this Firebase structure:

```
-users

--AQTbWsojNhbZMYwrteDptzMlpqN2

----KiUtRqCnxDdJS4kFX9h: true

----KofsazjH1OBoM4WVPr3: true

--cErsfz5X51Q7KwqtCbBZtwuCvEo2

----KofsazjH1OBoM4WVPr3: true
```

I need to delete all keys (for example -KofsazjH1OBoM4WVPr3) that correspond to a precise value that I have (detailId) in all of the users nodes (if it exist)

What I've done so far:

```swift
ref.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  if snapshot.exists(){
    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        for snap in snapshots {

                if snap.hasChild(detailId){

                snapshot.ref.child(snap.key).child(detailId).removeValue()

            }
        }
    }
  }
})
```

now in console i see that it delete only first occurrences of the detailId so for example in the snapshot below -KofsazjH1OBoM4WVPr3 is deleted only for user cErsfz5X51Q7KwqtCbBZtwuCvEo2

```js
   snapshot:  Snap (user) {
    AQTbWsojNhbZMYwrteDptzMlpqN2 =     {
        "-Kolc0zIZi2Cd7ongShd" = 1;
    };
    cErsfz5X51Q7KwqtCbBZtwuCvEo2 =     {
        "-KiUtRqCnxDdJS4kFX9h" = 1;
        "-KofsazjH1OBoM4WVPr3" = 1;
      
    };
    yUyw4kMGdpSwSn4pGBzhg5w7e9d2 =     {
        "-KocOfR1aHofFYu1HNna" = 1;
        "-KofsazjH1OBoM4WVPr3" = 1;
      
    };
}
```

Can somebody explain me what is wrong?

Comment: is that something about observeSingleEvent? the snapshot is only one...

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `observeSingleEvent` to `observe` will fetch all eligible results:

```
ref.child("users").observe(.value) { snapshot in
    if snapshot.exists(){
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {

                if snap.hasChild(detailId){

                    snapshot.ref.child(snap.key).child(detailId).removeValue()

                 }
             }
        }
    }
})
```

Then you go through the results as you mentioned.